# Flutter Fatal Exception: Cannot find Facebook CustomTabActivity

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I have deployed a Flutter app to the Android PlayStore using Firebase and Firebase Auth dependecies. Occasionally, Crashlytics catches the following error, which I am not able to reproduce on my emulators or test devices:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{myapp.myapp/com.facebook.CustomTabActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.CustomTabActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/myapp.myapp-WRz8otpImG-dv6UrzC9laA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/myapp.myapp-WRz8otpImG-dv6UrzC9laA==/split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk", zip file "/data/app/myapp.myapp-WRz8otpImG-dv6UrzC9laA==/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/myapp.myapp-WRz8otpImG-dv6UrzC9laA==/split_config.mdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/myapp.myapp-WRz8otpImG-dv6UrzC9laA==/lib/arm, /data/app/myapp.myapp-WRz8otpImG-dv6UrzC9laA==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/myapp.myapp-WRz8otpImG-dv6UrzC9laA==/split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/myapp.myapp-WRz8otpImG-dv6UrzC9laA==/split_config.en.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/myapp.myapp-WRz8otpImG-dv6UrzC9laA==/split_config.mdpi.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2843)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
   at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

The error does not seem to be tied to specific devices and I am not aware that I have implemented Facebook Auth. I assume that even though I only allow authentication with Google accounts, Firebase Auth still somehow depends on Facebook because it is part of the package.

Is there any way I can make Firebase Auth find the missing class?